# Vertically aligning content in CSS

Tags: css, position, vertical-alignment

I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LgNp5/ .

As you can see there is a loader on the right hand side. The left hand side has a menu with dynamically changing content and as such the right hand side floating div does not have a fixed height (nor does the parent element). How can I make it so that the loader is always vertically aligned (without JS)?

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest if the element you're vertically centering is a fixed height, that way you set `top: 50%;` and a `margin-top: -Zpx` where `` `Z `` is half the vertical height.

```
#ui-tooltip-prompt .dynamo_content {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
    padding-left:8px;
    position:absolute;
    height:16px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-8px;    
}
```

Comment: Could you show me the edited code via JS Fiddle? I've tried applying your suggestion but the height of .dynamo_content gets messed up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LgNp5/1/ - Forgot to mention that I took all the styles off of dynamo_content as well